# Custom ImageButton View

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener

I made a custom button that is an odd shape so I overrode the `dispatchTouchEvent.
Then I added a onTouch listener to make the image change when touched.
The onClick attribute stopped working so I added an onClick Listener. 
now neither the onClick listener or the onClick attribute are firing
Does anybody know why? I cant seem to resolve this.

this is the custom view:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        double iX = (double) event.getX();
        double iY = (double) event.getY();
        String isLeft = (String) getContentDescription();
        double Ymax;
        if(isLeft.equals("left"))
            Ymax = Math.sqrt((this.getWidth()*getWidth()) - ((getWidth() - iX)*(getWidth() - iX)) + (getHeight()*1.2));
        else
            Ymax = Math.sqrt((this.getWidth()*getWidth()) - ((iX)*(iX)) + (getHeight()*1.2));

            if (!(iY>Ymax || iY<0.0 || iX>getWidth() || iX<0.0)) {
                return false;
            }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

In mainActivity onCreate:

```
final CornerButton LeftCornerButton = (CornerButton) findViewById(R.id.LeftButton);
    LeftCornerButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)){
                LeftCornerButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cornerleft);
            }
            else{
                LeftCornerButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cornerleftdark);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    LeftCornerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showEvents(v);
        }
    });
```

The touch detection works perfectly and the image flipping works well too.
I can't put the click operations in the `(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) else` blcock because it calls the intent multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `true` from the method `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`, doing this you are telling the system that you are handling all the touch events, if you want for the click events to be detected, return `false` in the method `onTouch`